# How to disable crash reports on Kubuntu 14.04?

Tags: crash

I'm runnig Kubunu 14.04 and I keep getting a crash report tool popping up. How can remove it?

Comment: I mean this tool:   http://i.imgur.com/X4xs44w.png

Comment: This thing is called "drkonqi " and it should never be included in a stable release!!! Plus it is nowhere in the software sources!! How can I UNinstall this Mess!! this contradicts the idea of "free software". I can't even modify my OS!!!